Applying operators to quantum states
I am reading a primer on quantum proofs (without having a background in QM) ("Quantum Proofs" by Thomas Vidick and John Watrous, pages 11 and 15) and have a question.
For an operator $A\in L(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ (the set of linear maps from Hilbert space $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathcal{Y}$), the $(x,y)$ entry is given by $\langle x|A|y\rangle$. This suggests that the matrix representation of $A$ has $\textrm{dim}(\mathcal{X})$ rows and $\textrm{dim}(\mathcal{Y})$ columns in order for that product to make sense.
However, later the Stinespring representation of a quantum channel $\Phi:L(\mathcal{X})\rightarrow L(\mathcal{Y})$ is defined in terms of the Hilbert space $\mathcal{Z}$ and isometric operator $A\in L(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}\otimes\mathcal{Z})$ by the (partial trace) equation $\Phi(X)=\textrm{Trace}_{\mathcal{Y}}(AXA^*)$ for every $X\in L(\mathcal{X})$. For this product to make sense, it seems like the matrix representation of $A$ has $\textrm{dim}(\mathcal{X})$ columns and $\textrm{dim}(\mathcal{Y})$ rows.
What is the number of rows and columns in the matrix representation for an operator $A\in L(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$?

Detailed reference? Book/paper, chapter, page, equation number(s)...

Normally the $x \rightarrow y$ matrix element would be written as $\langle y| A | x \rangle$. I can easily believe this is a typo, although I would double check the source

Yeah, you've got the first matrix element backwards. It should be $\langle y | A |x \rangle$, as noted by @BySymmetry. You can see this from the Dirac notation by inserting two resolutions of the identity:
$$
\hat{A} = \sum_{xy}|y\rangle\langle y | \hat{A} | x\rangle \langle x |,,
$$
which shows that this operator accepts an $x$-state and spits out a $y$-state, roughly speaking. (I'm not sure that Dirac notation is the right choice for linear operators between different spaces, but this spells out the order correctly.)

@TobiasFünke "Quantum Proofs" by Thomas Vidick and John Watrous, pages 11 and 15. I'm pretty confident what I wrote is the same as what's in the text, and I already know of at least one other fairly obvious typo so i guess that's on them?

Please add the reference (with link!) to the question.

If $e_i$, $i=1,\ldots,d_X$ is a basis of $\mathcal{X}$ and $f_i$, $i=1,\ldots,d_Y$ is a basis of $\mathcal{Y}$ the matrix representation of the linear operator $A$ that you consider is given by $A_{j,i}$ defined by
$$
Ae_i = \sum_{j=1}^{d_Y} A_{j,i} f_j
$$
So $A_{j,i}$ is a $d_Y \times d_X$ matrix. This is consistent with the rule for matrix-vector multiplication.
Note that there is no need for a scalar product. In case you do have a scalar product and the bases are orthonormal with respect to the scalar product then
you can compute the coefficients via
$$
A_{j,i}= \langle f_j, A e_i \rangle
$$
But usually in this situation $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{Y}$.
